# Как включить номер вкладки в Intellij редакторах?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains, rider

Красным цветом выделены номера вкладок (визуальный хоткей).

Где включить/отключить показ данных символов?

[image: Rider]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откройте `Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance` и включите/отключите опцию `Show tool window numbers`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]